# What is the purpose of the php-cli package?

Tags: package-management, php, php-cli

During the process of setting up a new development workstation (Kubuntu 18.10), I discovered that the `php-cli` package was not installed. Nevertheless, all PHP scripts are working fine, whether they are run through the webserver or standalone (for example from cron).

I installed PHP using `apt install php`. This created a `php.ini` and a `conf.d` directory in `/etc/php/7.2/cli`. On the terminal, the path for the PHP executable is `/usr/bin/php`, which links to `/etc/alternatives/php`, which links to the actual binary, `/usr/bin/php7.2`. The MD5-sum of this file is the same with the `php-cli` package installed or removed.

I remember there used to be a time when `php-cli` was required for standalone scripts, but what does it do now? Is there any point in installing it, if the `php` package is already installed?

Comment: see https://github.com/splitbrain/php-cli

Comment: see https://github.com/splitbrain/php-cli

Comment: I don't think that's the same software. The description of the Ubuntu package reads *"This package provides the /usr/bin/php7.2 command interpreter"*. But your comment did help me figure out what's actually going on.

Comment: sure but it explains what it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

I must be blind, sorry: `php-cli` depends on `php7.2-cli`, which was automatically installed when I installed the `php` package. I missed that when I filtered the packages using "php-".

So the answer is: no, there is no point in installing `php-cli` after `php`, as nothing new would be added. In theory, it might be useful if I ever uninstall `php` or `libapache2-mod-php7.2`, as the CLI part would still be kept.